# How can I put xaml build definitions in source control in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: tfs, build, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2015 and TFS 2012.  In Team Explorer, it is possible to manage Builds and Build Definitions. Since VS2015, the section Build Definitions is named "XAML Build Definitions".  I would like to put xaml build definitions in source control. Problem is I cannot find the build definition files on disk.  Anyone knows where they are ?
Thanks

Comment: They're obviously not called that. What do you mean? Use your words.

Comment: I was assuming they would be in known folder, such as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\...".  Obviously that folder isn't named "Build definitions" ;)

Comment: Which version of TFS do you have?

Comment: tfs 2012.  Updated my question.

Comment: If you're talking about the version of the IDE required to open your solution, that's stored in the solution (and related project files) themselves.

Comment: I don't see anything related to build definitions in my solution or projects.  Now I am beginning to think they are saved on the Team Foundation server.  If that is the case, is there a way to source/version control these xaml files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download build process template and add it into source control, but you can't version-control build definitions.

In the new build system coming with TFS 2015 you can see the full history of the changes to your build definition. The feature that is currently missing is the ability to undo or rollback to a previous revision. Check https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037625-provide-a-way-to-version-control-build-definitions

Comment: Do you know the reason I can't version-control the build definitions ? Since they are named "xaml", I assume (maybe wrongly) that they are files, therefore, could be found somewhere and be version-controlled like any other file, no?

Comment: No. You can only download build process template and add it into source control. Build process template is a .xaml file.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone needs to access the XAML Build Definitions parameters. They are saved in the TFS database, table: `[dbo].[tbl_BuildDefinition]`.